# existence of finite irreducible reprentation of a nonunital $C^*$ algebra

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Suppose $A$ is a non-unital $C^*$ algebra,can we conclude that there must exist a nonzero finite irreducible representation of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot guarantee the existence of such a representation.  Consider $K(H)$, for $H$ a separable infinite-dimensional Hilbert space.  This is non-unital and simple, so any representation of this has to be infinite-dimensional.

Comment: This is because $K(H)$ is simple.  The kernel of a representation $(\varphi,K)$ is an ideal, hence must either be $0$ or $K(H)$.  Since we want nonzero representations, such a representation must be faithful, and thus $\varphi(K(H))\subset B(K)$ must be infinite-dimensional.